# dynamically highlighting a tab using css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and I want to highlight the currently selected tab using css.

```
<div id="Maintabs">
  <ul class"tablist">
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Summary"  target=_top>Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Advanced" target=_top>Advanced</a></li>
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Expert" target=_top>Expert</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

is there any way I can do this? I know css hover gives the element on which mouse is hovere, is there something similar for selected

thanks guys,

yes I do need dynamic handling, so I did the way you told. I capture the click event on that tab and the class. in css I apply the required styles to that class but it doesn't work.

here is my code:

in javaScript:

```
  $('#summary').click(function(){
              $(this).addClass("selected");
        alert(" summary");
          });
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="Maintabs">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 100px;"><a id="summary" href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Summary"  target=_top>Summary</a></li>
            <li style="width: 100px;"><a id="advanced" href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Advanced" target=_top>Advanced</a></li>
            <li style="width: 100px;"><a id="expert" href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Expert" target=_top>Expert</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.selected{
    background-color:#FEE0C6;
}
```

what do you think I am doing wrong??

Comment: what makes it into a tab? are you using JS?

Comment: Your question doesn't clearly explain the situation
Why don't you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: And if you're using a JS solution to achieve those tabs, then you should have a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
It automatically gives a 'selected' class to the active tab

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are using pure CSS to produce a tab effect. You would normally need Javascript or jQuery to dynamically change what the current tab is.

However, if you *are* using Javascript or jQuery for the tab effect, you could simply add a class to highlight the selected tab.

For example, this could be your jQuery:

```
$("#tab1").addClass("selected-tab");
```

And this your CSS:

```
.selected-tab
{
    /*Some style to highlight it and show it's the selected tab*/   
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but this doesn't solve the problem.
Posted my code above

Comment: Are you either using Javascript or jQuery to create the tab effect?

Comment: Ok. So when you run the jQuery code that makes a tab the selected one, use the code above to add a new class name. Note that `#tab1` is only an example name, and you should substitute your own tab ID or class. To test the code, click on a tab and inspect the HTML. Does the tab now have the new class?

Comment: I did exactly the same thing you are telling me. I put a alert which i do get when i click on the tab, but not the class. I did a "view source" of the HTML page even it doesn't show the class

Comment: So when you click on the tab, use `$(this).addClass("selected-tab")` to add the class. This should work 100%. If not, please create a jsfiddle at jsfiddle.net, save it, and share the URL so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in the jsfiddle. It works now: http://jsfiddle.net/P7KFk/11/

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to make an active class. By giving your li the defined class active. Then you can use css to make the .active a different color, size, shape, etc

Here's an example (first li):

**HTML**

```
<div id="Maintabs">
  <ul class"tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Summary"  target=_top>Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Advanced" target=_top>Advanced</a></li>
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Expert" target=_top>Expert</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an example (second li):

**HTML**

```
<div id="Maintabs">
  <ul class"tablist">
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Summary"  target=_top>Summary</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Advanced" target=_top>Advanced</a></li>
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Expert" target=_top>Expert</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an example (third li):

**HTML**

```
<div id="Maintabs">   <ul class"tablist">
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Summary"  target=_top>Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Advanced" target=_top>Advanced</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="AshukuWeb.jsp?VIEW=Expert" target=_top>Expert</a></li>  
 </ul> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#maintabs.active {background-color: #000;}
#maintabs {background-color: #ccc;}
```

The result will be the active tab being black (#000), and the inactive tabs being light grey (#ccc)

Comment: You should add that this is not possible with pure CSS, since the class needs to be added dynamically, using Javascript.